# Open a file in Google Drive programmatically not using Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have an application that receives a Google Drive File URL. Something like this:

https://docs.google.com/a/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoDnOTP7MiABdF9VSEFNMktmeDY4MkNHS3NDdk5JMmc#gid=0

I'm still not sure if will be the full https url or only the key value

I need to do 2 things:

1) Check if Google Drive Aplication for Android is intalled in the phone.

2) Call the Google Drive Android Aplication with that url to open the file. The ideal way is without opening any web browser. I want to use something like an Intent with extras, is this possible?

Thanks for you help and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry its easy now, i have solution for this problem. If you want to open any file which you have retrieved from Drive, then this can be done easily while using the resources of Google Drive app. First of all install the Google Drive app from play market [Install Google Drive app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs)

After that use this code to open your file.

```
   FileID=file.getId();//it is your file ID which you want to display

  String url = "https://docs.google.com/file/d/"+FileID;
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(i);
```

> This will open your file of any type(image, pdf,doc,txt etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
String url="https://docs.google.com/a/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoDnOTP7MiABdF9VSEFNMktmeDY4MkNHS3NDdk5JMmc#gid=0";

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Also, you don´t need to download googleDrive. Any anybody with the link can access the file or folder